# How to POST an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, html, associative-array

I have the following form:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="deptid" id="deptid" />
    <input type="text" name="deptname" id="deptname" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Is it possible to pass the two values into one associative array **BEFORE** submission ?
I would like to pass it in this form:

```
array('deptid'=>'deptname')
```

I need this because I avoid to modify the script of the destination php file(options.php)

Thanks.

Comment: @HankyPanky - What does cURL have to do with this?

Comment: Because he said "using only php script". So if he has to post data on this page using only php script so for a beginner i thought cURL would be good.

Comment: @HankyPanky - That would be if the server is contacting another server to pull information back to the server. This is client to server to client and back to the server...? I don't know where the cURL would come into the picture.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question then. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a method using pure HTML that get's you *nearly* exactly where you want to be, and only uses HTML:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="options[deptid]" id="deptid" />
    <input type="text" name="options[deptname]" id="deptname" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Which would give you in PHP:

```
$post_options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'deptid '=> '[that input element value]',
        'deptname' => '[that input element value]'
    )
);
```

Which you can then (*including sanitizing*) access such as this:

```
$post_options = array('options');

if (is_numeric($post_options['deptid'] && $post_options['deptid'] > 0) {
    // Do whatever 
}

if (is_string($post_options['deptname'] && strlen($post_options['deptname'] > 2)) {
    // Do whatever 
}
```

**EDIT**

Or... You want to reference the `deptid` in the `input name` attribute and use it to modify the row for a department name? Which seems to indicate something like this:

```
<?php

$deptid = 1;
$deptname = 'Department of Silly Walks';

?><input type="hidden" name="options[<?=$deptid?>]" value="<?=$deptname?>">
```

Which outputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="options[1]" value="Department of Silly Walks">
```

http://codepad.org/DtgoZGe7

The problem with this is that the `$deptid` value becomes a value that's not actually directly named or referenced. I think this is potentially problematic to implement due to this abstraction of the value from the server to the client and back, so I would recommend what I have at the top instead. It's not much of a difference in practice, but it's more or less self-documenting.

Note, if you wanted to serialize a list of departments, it's a little trickier. You might, for instance, try this:

```
<input type="text" name="options[][deptid]" id="deptid" />
<input type="text" name="options[][deptname]" id="deptname" />
```

Which would add an indexed value for every `input`. However... They were would not be directly associated. So you would get, instead, two zero-indexed arrays for each key.

What I would suggest in this case is to use Javascript to add each new department's `input` elements, so you can give each a number like:

```
<input type="text" name="options[0][deptid]" id="deptid" />
<input type="text" name="options[0][deptname]" id="deptname" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="options[1][deptid]" id="deptid" />
<input type="text" name="options[1][deptname]" id="deptname" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="options[2][deptid]" id="deptid" />
<input type="text" name="options[2][deptname]" id="deptname" />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="options[3][deptid]" id="deptid" />
<input type="text" name="options[3][deptname]" id="deptname" />
```

Or do the old-school POSTBACK method and use PHP to count `$POST['options']` and "manually" add a new "row" of inputs with the same index. It's a common trap, so you just have to think about it if this is what you're after at some point.

Comment: well in this case it still the same... an array within another array

Comment: @Mahan - Exactly. It's very useful; see my edit for a syndication example, when you have multiple new entries and you want to manage the list of departments directly through the POST `options` array.

Comment: well I'm just following the code of the OP, let's see if he changes it later on

Comment: @Mahan - This is what was provided: `array('deptid'=>'deptname')`. That, without client-side Javascript manipulating the `input` values (for instance, as a hidden value that's modified `onsubmit`), what that seems to indicate is decoupling the name from the row ID. So it could just be the OP needs `<input type="hidden" name="<?=$deptid?>" value="<?=$deptname?>">`. Which I just thought of. Hmm. So hopefully we'll hear from the OP.

Comment: @user1134475 - You'll have to use PHP to get the `$deptid` and `$deptname` from your database or source and insert it (using a template approach, for instance). It's just wherever you're storing that data. A typical approach to this is the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern, too.

Comment: @Jared - thanks for the very long answer. I have edited my question. I need the associates array before submitting to destination php, in this case is options.php. Is it possible to this without javascript?

Answer (score 6):

**`$_POST` is already an associative array** and *I recommend you not to complicate things beyond that* because **`$_POST` already holds the data came from your form**.

```
$myassoc = $_POST;
print_r($myassoc);
```

and the associative array that you will receive is organized and named same in the name attribute of the input elements in your form (including textarea)

**Other Insights**

As I see your code you want to put the `deptname` data to `deptid` as it reaches the PHP server-side code. well the thing you can do with is is just assign it to the key `deptid`

```
$_POST['deptid'] = $_POST['deptname'];
$myassoc = $_POST;
print_r($myassoc);
```

Comment: I had something completely different I think the OP was after; POST is associative, but I think the OP wants the *keys and values* to be associated *within* the POST array.

Comment: so something like he want to `merge` it with the POST array?

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="formdata['deptid']" />
    <input type="text" name="formdata['deptname']" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['formdata']))
    {
       $deptid = $_POST['formdata']['deptid'];
       $deptname = $_POST['formdata']['deptname'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a JS object with the appropriate structure, convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`, POST it, and then do `json_decode($_POST['data'],true)`.

You'll have an exact copy from JS object, to PHP associate array. Drop the second parameter of `true` to get a PHP object.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is already an associative array.

You can rebuild an array of the form you need from this by just assigning `$_POST` to a variable

```
$myarray = $_POST;
```

Now $myarray is what you require.  Do `var_dump($myvar);`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to modify the php script in server (options.php)

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do that? 
But, you CAN send "arrays" through forms like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
    <input type="text" name="textboxes[]" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['textboxes']))
        var_dump($_POST['textboxes']);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$deptid = $_POST['deptid'];
$array = array($$deptid => $_POST['deptname']);
print_r($array);
```