# User filled HTML table to php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I already created a HTML table from an array, but some cells were inputs. The idea is to have some fixed data in cells and some input boxes where you input your own.

I saved the html form into a variable which I used in the array. Looks something like this:

```
$input='<form action="test.php" method="post"><input type=text></input></form>';

 $array = array(
    array('1', '2', $input, '4', '5', '6', $input, '8', $input, '10'),
    array('11', $input, '13, $input, '15', '16', $input, '18', '19', $input),);
```

test.php is where the comparison code would be.

After filling the entire table the user would press enter and it would tell them if the order of the number was correct by comparing it with a similar array that has all the numbers.

I tried comparing `$_POST` with the array that contains answers but it isn't as simple as that.

I would just like to know how the whole table (with fixed data and input numbers) could be saved into an array like the one above so I would be able to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $_POST or $_GET array in php you should use array form in name property :
[How to POST an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050812/how-to-post-an-associative-array-in-php)

```
<input type="text" name="num[]">
```

for your code Test this :

main page :
    $input='';

```
 $array =array('1', '2', $input, '4', '5', '6', $input, '8', $input, '10');

echo '<table><tr>';
echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
foreach($array as $num){
    if($num != $input){
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" value="'.$num.'" name="num[]">'.$num.'</td>';
    } 
    if($num == $input){
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="num[]"></td>';
    }

}
echo '<input type="submit"></form>';

echo '</table></tr>';
```

And test page :

```
$num=$_POST['num'];
var_dump($num);
```